# Form stay on same page after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

My page keeps submitting even after it shows the alert message and the return false code is clearly present. What am I doing wrong here?

```
     function validateForm () {
        var selected = "";
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("special");
        var len = document.getElementsByName("special").length;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(radios[i].checked) {
                selected = radios[i].value;
                break;
            }
            if(selected == "") {
                alert("Must select option.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
     }

    <form action="FormProcessor.html" method="post" onreset="blank();" onsubmit="validateForm();" name="myForm">
            <p>Would you like special offers sent to you e-mail?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="special" value="Yes"/>Yes
            <input type="radio" name="special" value="No"/>No<br/>
            <input type="submit"/>
            <input type="reset"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to just say like this

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

instead of

```
onsubmit="validateForm();"
```

## [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/114/)

That was because you were checking the value of `selected` in `for` loop, so for first time it's value is `""` second time it's become `No`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Now, seeing the code, can you explain why the alert("Must select option") is showing even if the option "No" is checked?

Comment: Thanks! What would be a better way to write this code then to work correctly?

Comment: It is. I'm not seeing any changes to the code though to make it work correctly? Am I missing something?

Comment: @turd.ferguson If you'll see, I'm closing `for` loop just after first `if` check, but in your code, all `if` conditions were being checked in `for`.

Comment: OH! Haha. I don't know why I didn't see that. As you can tell, I'm very new to JavaScript. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In your submit handler, instead of `return false`, use `event.preventDefault`.

```
function validateForm (event) {
...
        if(selected == "") {
            alert("Must select option.");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

You'll have to do something more involved to support IE8.

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

Alternatively, you can change the `onsubmit` attribute to be `return validateForm()`. That will both prevent the default action and stop the event propagation, rather than just prevent the default action.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the return validateForm() . It was a quick easy fix! Would you know why the it keeps showing the alert("Must select option") even if the option "No" is checked?

Comment: Your loop logic is such that it fires the alert the first time through if the first item isn't checked rather than firing the alert after looping through everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to write return before the onsubmit() method in form.

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

When you don't write return before the method call of onSubmit() then the javascript can not return the page back into the form.